# fill values from cell above in a given column

Tags: python, pandas

For the column labelled "Category", I want to fill the cells with white spaces with the value from above, see df number 2 in image below.

Here is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
df[df['Category']==" "] = np.NaN
df = df['Category'].fillna(method='ffill')
col = ['Category']
df.loc[:,col] = df.loc[:,col].ffill()
df.loc[:,['Category']] = df.loc[:,['Category']].ffill()
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
col = ['Category']
df.loc[:,col] = df.loc[:,col].ffill()
```

I want to then keep the 2nd instance of each row (if that makes sense), see df 3 in image below.

[image]

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe, don't show images

Comment: why is row `17` still in your data frame?

Comment: `df['Category']=df['Category'].ffill()`?

Comment: "if that makes sense" is not quite the best way to define a rule for dropping rows.

Comment: You can use the [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method. Define the to_replace argument to the blank field and select your desired fill-method in your case it should be 'ffill'.

Comment: @ansev I've tried this but it did not work, maybe because the cells are not empty, they have a white space in them.

Comment: then `df['Category']=df['Category'].mask(df['Category'].eq('')|df['Category'].isnull()).ffill()`

Comment: You are welcome, please accpet my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can transform to NaN using [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then drop duplicated:

```
df['Category']=df['Category'].mask(df['Category'].eq('')|df['Category'].isnull()).ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

With @ansev's help I have a working version of the code:

```
#fill whitespaces in 'Category' with values from cell above
df['Category'] = df['Category'].mask(df['Category'].eq('')).ffill()

#drop duplicates in column 'Category' and keep last instance
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Category'], keep='last')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Base', 152],
     ['Male', 98], ['-', .64],
     ['Female', 52], ['-', .34],
     ['Non-binary', '-'], ['-', '-'],
     ['Prefer-not', 2], ['-', .01]],
    columns=('category', 'engagement')
)

df = df.replace('-', np.nan)
df['category'] = df['category'].ffill()
```

Result:

```
            engagement
category              
Base            152.00
Female            0.34
Male              0.64
Non-binary         NaN
Prefer-not        0.01
```

Comment: the problem is that he has '' values...therefore we need convert to NaN before